# Creating a function to rotate an array of ints a given amount of steps

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

So I made a thing:

```
function rotate(array, [steps]){
    var array_length = array.length;
    var real_steps = 1;
    var new_array = [];
    if (typeof steps !== 'undefined')
    {
        real_steps = steps;
    }
    else
    {
    steps = 1;  
    }

    if (real_steps > array_length)
    {
        real_Steps = steps % array_length;
    }
    else if (real_steps < 0)
    {
        if (real_steps % 2)
        {
            real_steps = real_steps*(-1)+2;
        }
        else
        {
            real_steps = real_steps*(-1);   
        }
        real_steps = steps % array_length;
    }

    else if (real_steps === 0)
    {
        return array;
    }
    for(var i=0; i<=array_length-real_steps; i++)
        new_array[i] = array[i+real_steps];
    for(var i=array_length-real_steps; i<array_length-real_steps;i++)
        new_array[i] = array[i];
    return new_array
}
```

The purpose of the function is to take in an array of integers and move the integers around by a given amount of steps. The steps default to 1 if they're undefined.

I'm having trouble testing the program as simply slapping

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
rotate(a);
```

does not work. The code itself has a problem that I think is caused by an undefined [steps] throwing an exception, but I can't be sure as to what the problem is without being able to test it out myself.

How can I test the function's output?

And in a lesser detail, is there any obvious problems with my function at the current stage?

Comment: `move the integers around by a given amount of steps` what do you mean by this?

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?

Comment: When the [steps] arg is undefined, the program throws an exception "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined"

And the ideal functionality would be that if the step was one, [1,2,3,4] would become [4,1,2,3]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some issues in the function:

- The syntax for an optional `step` parameter is not `[step]`, but just `step`: in JavaScript all arguments are optional. You can however give a default value with `step = 1` inside the parameter list.
- The modulo 2 (`%2`) is strange: I don't see how that helps in treating negative steps. You can instead treat all step values with this formula:

  ```
  steps - Math.floor(steps / array.length) * array.length
  ```
- It is a lot of code for something that can be easily done with `slice` and `concat`
- You did not provide code where you read the return value of the function. It is good practice that the function does not alter the original array (so keep it that way), but maybe you expected `a` to be modified by `rotate(a)`? Anyway, the result is *returned* by the function, so you can just output that or store it in a variable.

Code:

```js
function rotate(array, steps = 1){ // Optional argument notation is not []
    steps = steps - Math.floor(steps / array.length) * array.length; // works also OK for negative
    return array.slice(steps).concat(array.slice(0, steps));
}

// Demo
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
for (var step = -6; step < 7; step++) {
    console.log('step ' + step + ' => ' + rotate(a, step));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

#### Version with in-place rotation

If you need the array to be mutated by the function, then use `splice`:

```js
function rotate(array, steps = 1){ // Optional argument notation is not []
    steps = steps - Math.floor(steps / array.length) * array.length; // works also OK for negative
    array.push(...array.splice(0, steps));
}

// Demo
for (var step = -6; step < 7; step++) {
    var a = [1,2,3,4,5]; // reset
    rotate(a, step);
    console.log('step ' + step + ' => ' + a);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: That's a comprehensive answer, thanks!

If I wanted to edit the global variable a within the function, I would just refer to it, in the function, or would I have to refer to the argument "array" of the rotate() -function?

Comment: That depends. If you want to assign an array to `array`, the global variable is not affected, but if you change `array[0]` then this will be seen in the global variable. But really it is better not to modify the global variable from within the function.

Comment: In case you are looking for an "inplace" rotation that mutates the array that it is being given: I added this variant to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
const array = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"];
let newArray = [];

function rotate(array, steps){
    for(i=0; i<array.length ; i++){
        if(i+steps < array.length){
            newArray.push(array[i+steps]);
        } else {
            newArray.push(array[i+steps-array.length])
        }
    }
}

rotate(array, 3);
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

The function returns the new rotated array, so you have to assign the result to something:

```
a = rotate(a);
```